# trying to start a new project and proguard.cfg not found

Tags: android, proguard

eclipse seemed to be working ok with the rest of my projects until i created a new project. As i try to create it a dialog pops up from eclipse saying cannot find C:\android\tools\lib...\proguard.cfg. if i go ahead and create the project then no R.java is generated. i've search stackover flow and rebuilding project or doing a project clean does not work. any ides? thanks

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned the error is  C:\android\tools\lib...\proguard.cfg.
Got the same error after installing some Google Plugins.

**How it worked for me:**

Just take any proguard.cfg from the any projects root folder(the projects that you have previously made) and then copy paste it in C:\android\tools\lib\ folder. Then try to make a new project and you wont get any problems.